# not a unquire alias in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a query

```
    SELECT  `user_deleted_bookmarks`.`bookmark_id` as 
`is_deleted`,`user_favourite_bookmarks`.`user_bookmark_id`
as `is_fav`,`user_bookmarks`.* FROM `user_bookmarks`  
RIGHT JOIN 
  `user_bookmarks` ON `user_favourite_bookmarks`.`user_bookmark_id` =`user_bookmarks`.`bookmark_id` 
    Right JOIN 
`user_bookmarks` ub ON `user_deleted_bookmarks`.`bookmark_id`=`ub`.`bookmark_id` 

     WHERE `user_bookmarks`.`user_id`=26 group by `user_bookmarks`.`bookmark_id` order by created_at DESC
```

when i am trying to run this query on phpmyadmin. it gives me error,  **not #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'user_bookmarks'**

Does anybody tell me how to resolve this issue

Thanks

Comment: You are joining twice on the same and mysql needs you to provide an alias for those.

Comment: how about removing one of them WHERE `user_bookmarks`.`user_id`=26 group by `user_bookmarks`.`bookmark_id`  
     WHERE `user_bookmarks`.`user_id`=26 group by `user_bookmarks`.`bookmark_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just misspelled your table name. Replace the second user_bookmark with user_ favourite_bookmark

```
FROM `user_bookmarks`  
RIGHT JOIN 
`user_ favourite_bookmarks` ON `user_favourite_bookmarks`.`user_bookmark_id` =`user_bookmarks`.`bookmark_id`
```

Comment: Can't Vote up. Due to low rating

Answer (score 0):

You're using user_bookmarks in the FROM and then joining again without aliasing the join.  Try adding an alias to the first user_bookmark right join